# Add dash at the end and beginning of a string

Tags: regex

I want a dash to be added at the end and beginning of a string.

Example:

```
"chicken" -> "-chicken-"  
"nuggets" -> "-nuggets-"
```

So I'm pretty much asking for Regexes.

Comment: `sed s/.*/-&-/`. At least try next time. - Replace `.` with `[^ \t]` if you define a string as stuff between whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is:

```
/^(.*)$/-\1-/
```

But why don't you add dashes without regex? I mean, why not to use string operators? Like `str = '-' + str +'-';` or `$str = "-" . $str . "-"`, etc. depending on your programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
^|$
```

And replace with `-` (dash)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL7dX9/5)

**PS:** Use it with `m` (multiline) flag.